# VSCode re-installation problems on macbook

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

After vscode crashed, I have uninstalled it from my macbook by moving it to trash but i also deleted it from trash and tried to install it from the website but the downloaded zip shows archived utility and opens an IDE. But there is no vscode application in the system.

I later checked website for proper uninstall and did all that is required. restarted my macbook and tried downloading it again. The same happens. Can anyone guide how to re-install VSCode application?

Comment: what do you see when you run `code --verbose --log debug` in a terminal?

Comment: Sorry for responding late. Checked it just now. It says - zsh: command not found: code

Comment: replace `code` in that command with the full path to your VS Code executable.

Comment: gives - zsh: no such file or directory